# Convert indexed image into grayscale

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

How can I convert an RGB or indexed images into gray scale without using `B=ind2gray(A,map)` from MATLAB?

Comment: Since you haven't told us which language you're using, about the only thing we can suggest is: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: What's the objection to ind2gray?

Comment: None, but I should create a function simuling ind2gray that is able to convert RGB and indexed images in grayscale. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you just can't use `ind2gray`.... but if you really have to implement this from first principles, that's actually not too bad.  What `ind2gray` does (IIRC) is that it takes an indexed image and with the colour map, it converts the image into a colour image.  Once you're done that, you convert the resulting colour image to grayscale.  The index image is actually a grid of lookup values that span from `[1,N]`.  Also, the colour map is a `N x 3` array where each row is a RGB tuple / colour.  It should be noted that the colour map is `double` precision where each component spans between `[0,1]`.  Therefore, for each location in the index image, it tells you **which** tuple from the lookup table is mapped to this location.  For example, if we had an index image such that:

```
X = 
[1  2
 3  4]
```

... and we had a colour map that was 4 x 3, this means that the top left corner gets the first colour denoted by the first row of the map, the top right corner gets the second colour, bottom left corner gets the third colour and finally the bottom right corner gets the fourth colour.

The easiest way to do this would be to use `X` to index into each column of the input map, then concatenate all of the results together into a single 3D matrix.  Once you're done, you can convert the image into its luminance / grayscale counterpart.  Given that you have an index image called `X` and its corresponding colour map, do this:

```
colour_image = cat(3, map(X), map(X + size(map,1)), map(X + 2*size(map,1)));
gray = sum(bsxfun(@times, colour_image, permute([0.2126 0.7152 0.0722], [3 1 2])), 3);
```

The first statement is very simple.  Take note that `map` is `N x 3` and `X` can range between `[1,N]`.  If we use `X` and index directly into `map`, you would only be grabbing the first column of values, or the first component of the colours / red.  We need to access the same values in the right order for the second column, and because MATLAB accesses elements in column-major format, we simply have to add all of the offsets by `N` so that we can access the values in the second column to get the second component of colours / green.  Finally, you'd offset by `2N` to get the third component of colours / blue.  We'd take each red, green and blue channel and concatenate them together to get a 3D image.

Once we get this 3D image, it's a matter of converting the colour image into luminance.  I am using the [SMPTE Rec. 709 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29#Use_of_luminance) to convert from a colour pixel to luminance.  That relationship is:

```
Y = 0.2126 R + 0.7152 G + 0.0722 B
```

That's the purpose of the second statement.  We will take each component, multiply them by their respective weight and sum all of the values together.  You should have your luminance image as a result.

To check to see if this works, we can use the `trees` dataset from the image processing toolbox.  This comes with an index image `X`, followed by a colour map `map`:

```
load trees;

%// Previous code
colour_image = cat(3, map(X), map(X + size(map,1)), map(X + 2*size(map,1)));
gray = sum(bsxfun(@times, colour_image, permute([0.2126 0.7152 0.0722], [3 1 2])), 3);

%// Show colour image as well as resulting gray image
figure; subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(colour_image);
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(gray);
```

We get:

[image]

We can actually show that this is indeed the right output by converting the image to grayscale using `ind2gray`, then showing the difference between the two images.  If the images are equal, that means that the resulting image should be black, which means that the outputs produced by the above procedure and `ind2gray` are exact.

Therefore:

```
gray2 = ind2gray(X, map);
figure;
imshow(abs(gray-gray2));
```

We get:

[image]

... yup... zilch, nothing, zero, notta.... so what I implemented in comparison to `ind2gray` is basically the same thing.

Comment: Another quality answer!